# Rails link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following route in my rails application:

```
recipient_template DELETE /templates/:id/recipient/:recipient_type/:recipient_id(.:format)
```

How can I create a link in my view to this specific route given that both recipient type and recipient id are dynamically filled by my application.

**Edit**

Here is my model and route.rb file

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :individuals
     has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

     def recipients
         {:groups => self.groups, :individuals => self.individuals}
     end
end

resources :templates do
    member do
        match 'recipient/:recipient_type/:recipient_id', :to => :recipient_remove, :via => :delete
    end
end
```

Comment: have you tried running `rake routes` ? it should give the answer!

Comment: `link_to('Template', recipient_template_path(recipient_type: recipient_type,recipient_type: recipient_type ))` may work...

Comment: @xlembouras What I provided above is form rake routes. What I am trying to achieve here is to delete a specific recipient from a model Template. recipients can be either groups or individuals so I have to specify the type as well as the id of the selected recipient.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I tried it out and what happens is: Started DELETE "/templates/1/recipient?recipient_id=id&recipient_type=type"

Comment: @ArupRakshit That will not work. And why are you passing `recipient_type ` twice anyways.

Comment: @KirtiThorat That's a typo.. I meant `link_to('Template', recipient_template_path(recipient_type: recipient_type,recipient_id: recipient_id))`

Comment: @mdoust I think you are using the object `@template` in side the view.. then  `@template.recipient_type` or `@template.recipient_id`..wouldn't work..?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes I got that it was a typo and response posted above is what I got...

Comment: @ArupRakshit my template's recipients may be either objects of 'Group' model or objects of 'Individual' model. I am trying to remove one of these recipients from this template but in order to do so I have to know both it's id and type to either call template.groups.find(:id).destroy or template.individuals.find(:id).destroy

Comment: It would be good, if you give the code in the view template.. That will be helpful..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I just edited the post to show the necessary segments of model and routes.rb file

Comment: Yes.. Good.. Now anyone can help you... Its Rails... every thing is needed to see.. basically M..V..C.. :-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

pass recipient_type and recipient_id values in path along with template id

```
link_to "Delete Recipient", recipient_remove_path(template.id, recipient_type, recipient_id), method: :delete
```

In your routes

```
match 'recipient/:recipient_type/:recipient_id' => "controller#action", :as => :recipient_remove, :via => :delete
```

and you  should pass recipient class name in recipient type and id of recipients in reciepient_id

Comment: Anil - how the value of `recipient_type` and `recipient_id` will be determined ?

Comment: I tried this and: Started DELETE "/templates/1/recipient.Group" and I got a routing error saying No route matches [DELETE] "/templates/1/recipient.Group"

Comment: @mdoust show the `routes.rb` content.. and the view also... It would be helpful.. for us to help you..

Comment: @KirtiThorat How is it helpful ? Why the parameter needed `method: :delete` in this case?

Comment: @mdoust If you are getting `Started DELETE "/templates/1/recipient.Group" ` as request then it just means that you have another route defined in `routes.rb` with `DELETE` verb and which is defined before `recipient_template`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Without `method: :delete` when you click the link, you will always get a `GET` HTTP request and not `DELETE`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat How the value `recipient_type, recipient_id` will be replaced there ? The same questions to *answerer* also..

Comment: In the **exact order** the `dynamic segments` are defined in the route `/templates/:id/recipient/:recipient_type/:recipient_id`

Comment: change match 'recipient/:recipient_type/:recipient_id', "Controller#action", :as => :recipient_remove, :via => :delete

Comment: @KirtiThorat They only other route with DELETE before this is for Devise controller.

Comment: @AnilMaurya That means real answer is still hanging some where else.. You could confirm it in comment first when not sure, then post as answer...

Comment: @KirtiThorat Are `http://exampe.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs` and `http://exampe.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu` different ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I was sure about my answer, and editing answer won't take that much time, that first i have to discuss answer in comment and then write answer

Comment: @AnilMaurya See your answer will be read by lots of people, when they will be having similar scenarios..Then they will be confused by seeing two answers and which one to pick, as there is no such explanations.. any way if OP marked, I would think it is helpful..